# What kind of tree implementation is STL set?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I know that in STL `vector` represents the implementation of a dynamic array. So does the `list` represents the implementation of a  linked list (doubly linked list). I know that `set` has an implementation similar to tree . Looking at the algorithm complexity as mentioned most of the inbuilt function in set is of complexity *o(1)* or *o(log n)*. So is this tree implemented as Balanced Tree or any other kind of tree such as red-black tree and if So Why such a tree structure was chosen ?

Comment: Do you really mean STL or just commonly mistaken with STL "C++ Standard Library"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard imposes no restrictions on the implementation (other than the complexity guarantees).

In other words, it's implementation-dependent.  Typically, it's a red-black tree (see e.g. `/usr/include/c++/x.y.z/bits/stl_tree.h`, where `x.y.z` is your particular GCC version).

Comment: I am using a std::set and inserting values inside it .I dont do it to make anything specific to a kind of tree my set should be Whether a binary or red black or a balanced . So is it really implementation dependent ?

Comment: @Ritesh: I'm not sure what your point is, but yes, it's really implementation-dependent.

Comment: "Implementation dependant" in the context of the C++ standard means it's up to the compiler/library vendor to decide how they implement it. It has nothing to do with how you write your library-using code, @Ritesh.

Comment: @oli Typically its a red black if user does not provide any implementation for it . Thats what you meant ?

Comment: @Ritesh, each person who writes a version of the STL might have done it differently.  Thats what implementation dependant means.  Most of them are red-black binary trees though.

Comment: @Ritesh, no.  The user (you) never gets to decide.  GCC/microsoft already decided for you.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks a lot especially the path part was very useful :)