# C++ std::set why is it associative?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Why is `std::set` defined as an associative container?

I mean `std::map` is an associative container because it maps a value to a key, but why is it a set?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore 23.4 and elsewhere.

Comment: It associates itself to itself...

Comment: The distinction in the standard is "sequence container" versus "associative container". While it's a bit of a stretch for a set to be "associative", it's a reasonable choice for that contrast in names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why std::set is an associative container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071335/why-stdset-is-an-associative-container)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 23.4.6.1 Class template set overview [set.overview]

> A `set` satisfies all of the requirements of [..] an associative
>   container (23.2.4) [...]

Because it satisfies all pre-conditions of being an associative container, which are described in `23.2.4.` and aren't as simple as "maps a key to a value".

The second paragraph even highlights this (or rather, highlights that it is in fact `map` and `multimap` have additional functionality over associative containers):

#### 23.2.4 Associative containers [associative.reqmts]

> 2) Each associative container is parameterized on Key and an ordering relation Compare that induces a strict
>   weak ordering (25.4) on elements of Key. In addition, map and multimap associate an arbitrary type T with
>   the Key. The object of type Compare is called the comparison object of a container.

The full paragraph is too large to reproduce here.

Comment: Got it, so it's not the key-value associativity that defines a container

Comment: @Luchian  Can we say std::set is container that is just like a sequential container with additional functionalities like sorted data and implementation in the form of red-black tree to provide O(logn) access

Comment: @cbinder I don't think the RB tree implementation is required.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375334/what-kind-of-tree-implementation-is-stl-set and also do note on my earlier comment whether that is reasonable to say or not.

Answer (score 2):

[reference at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)

In a set, the key is the value, which must be unique.

Edit:

"Elements in associative containers are referenced by their key and not by their absolute position in the container."