# Balancing a C++ set

Tags: c++, data-structures, set, std

As C++ sets are implemented in binary trees, if we insert items in incremental or decremental order, then the set would be more a list than a tree. Is there any method to balance the tree AFTER items are inserted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ sets (i.e. `std::set`) are usually implemented as [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). They are self balancing.

However it is implemented, your suggestion that the set would become more like a list cannot happen, because the standard makes complexity guarantees which cannot be fulfilled by a list.

Answer (score 1):

Although the standard imposes no restrictions on the implementation, it's usually a red-black tree. So the library deal with it well, and don't worry about it

Look [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375334/what-kind-of-tree-implementation-is-stl-set)